# .NET configuration with multiple instances of a set of parameters

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I have an application that can connect to several servers.  The actual number of servers is not known until runtime,and may change from day to day.  It takes several actual parameters to fully define a server.

I'm trying to configure the application using .NET support for application configurations.

The configuration file looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup
           name="userSettings"
            type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="server"
                type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler"
                allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser"
                requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <server name="washington">
            <add name="host" value="abc.presidents.com"/>
            <add name="port" value="1414"/>
            <add name="credentials" value="george"/>
        </server>
        <server name="adams">
            <add name="host" value="def.presidents.com"/>
            <add name="port" value="1419"/>
            <add name="credentials" value="john"/>
        </server>
        <!--insert more server definitions here -->
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

And I tried to read this with code something like this (the WriteLines are for diagnosing the problem.  They will go away when/if it works.):

```
try
{
    var exeConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    Console.WriteLine(exeConfiguration);

    var userSettings = exeConfiguration.GetSectionGroup("userSettings");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", userSettings, userSettings.Name);

    var sections = userSettings.Sections;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", sections, sections.Count);
    foreach (ConfigurationSection section in sections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", section);
        // todo Here's where we capture information about a server
    }

}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

This throws an exception from the foreach and produces the following output:

```
    System.Configuration.Configuration
    System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup: userSettings
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection: 1
    Exception: Sections must only appear once per config file.  See the help topic <location> for exceptions.
```

If I remove the second server, leaving only washington, it "works" producing this output:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionGroup: userSettings
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection: 1
System.Configuration.DefaultSection
```

I've tried other variations on the theme (nested sectionGroups, etc.) without finding a solution.  The various tutorial examples I've found seem to want me to create a separate class for each Server.  This is obviously impractical, and should be unnecessary since all servers are created equal.

Questions:

- Does System.Configuration support the concept of a collection of sets of related settings  (like an array of structures)?
- If so.. how?
- If not.. is there another way to store persistent configuration information that does support this concept, or am I going to have to roll-my-own?

## Progress Report

Based on the partial answer by Robert McKee I modified the xml like so:

```
            <section name="servers"
                type="System.Configuration.DefaultSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

and

```
<servers>
    <add name="washington" host="abc.presidents.com" port="1414" credentials="george"/>
    <add name="adams" host="def.presidents.com" port="1419" credentials="john"/>
    <!--insert more server definitions here -->
</servers>
```

This is an improvement with one fatal problem.  As you can see I changed the `type` attribute of the `section` element to name the class `ystem.Configuration.DefaultSection`  `DefaultSection` succeeds at reading the configuration information (I think, at least it does not complain.) but it does not expose any way to access the information it read!

Therefore I need to use some other type of `*Section` class. Microsoft provides 95 classes derived from the `ConfigurationSection` base class, but all of them except `DefaultSection` and `ClientSettingsSection` appear to be targeted at special cases (urls, database connection strings, date and times, etc...)  `ClientSettingsSection` won't even read the servers section -- complaining that `<add/>` is not a valid nested element.

So, bottom line is I'm going to have to write a custom `ConfigurationSection` to handle these settings.  If I get it working I'll add an answer with the ultimate solution (unless someone provide a better answer first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Conclusions

- Collections of property sets cannot be supported without creating custom property classes.
- Support for creating custom property classes is pretty good.
- Documentation for creating custom property classes is abysmal, however I did finally find a decent [overview document](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration) that helped me find an answer.

## The Configuration file

The app.config file I ended up with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
                      type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="executiveBranch" 
                     type="PropProto.Properties.ExecutiveBranchSection, PropProto, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" 
                     allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" 
                     requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <executiveBranch>
            <presidents>
                <president key="first"
                           name="George Washington"
                           legacy="The Fother of Our County"
                           />
                <president key="honestAbe"
                           name="Abraham Lincoln"
                           legacy="Freed the Slaves"
                           />
                <president key="who"
                           name="Chester Arthur"
                           />
                <president key="dubya"
                           name="George W. Bush"
                           legacy="Mission Accomplished!!!"
                           />
                <president key="barack"
                           name="Barack Obama"
                           legacy="Affordable Health Care"
                           />

            </presidents>
        </executiveBranch>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

There is one more nesting level than I had expected (or want).  That's because `presidents` is a `ConfigurationElementCollection` and `userSettings` cannot include a `ConfigurationElementCollection` directly, so I had to introduce `executiveBranch`.

## Using the Configuration

The code to read these settings is:

```
var exeConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
      ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
var userSettings = exeConfiguration.GetSectionGroup("userSettings");
var executiveBranch = (ExecutiveBranchSection)userSettings.Sections.Get(
        ExecutiveBranchSection.Tag);
var presidents = executiveBranch.Presidents;
foreach (President president in presidents)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", president.Name, president.Legacy);
}
```

## The Custom Properties Classes

And the custom classes to make all this work:

```
public class ExecutiveBranchSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    public const string Tag = "executiveBranch";
    [ConfigurationProperty(PresidentCollection.Tag)]
    public PresidentCollection Presidents { get { return (PresidentCollection)base[PresidentCollection.Tag]; } }
}

[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(President),
    CollectionType = ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap,
    AddItemName = President.Tag)]
public class PresidentCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public const string Tag = "presidents";
    protected override string ElementName { get { return President.Tag; } }

    public President this[int index]
    {
        get { return (President)base.BaseGet(index); }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }

            base.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    new public President this[string name] { get { return (President)base.BaseGet(name); } }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new President();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return (element as President).Key;
    }
}

public class President : ConfigurationElement
{
    public const string Tag = "president";
    [ConfigurationProperty("key", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Key { get { return (string)base["key"]; } }
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name { get { return (string)base["name"]; } }
    [ConfigurationProperty("legacy", IsRequired = false)]
    public string Legacy { get { return (string)base["legacy"]; } }
}
```

Comment: Thank your posting your final working result!

I took inspiration from this and from .Net Framework source code for ConnectionStringSettingsCollection, which looks quite similar to what you have here.
I'm posting this a link to the .Net reference source because it validates your approach, and contains a plethora of other useful implimentations to glean from.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.cs,ce6c273ea26349e5

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with custom config sections, but from a purely logical point of view, isn't this more appropriate:

```
<userSettings>
    <servers>
        <add name="washington" host="abc.presidents.com" port="1414" credentials="george"/>
        <add name="adams" host="def.presidents.com" port="1419" credentials="john"/>
        <!--insert more server definitions here -->
    </servers>
    <!-- insert more user settings here -->
</userSettings>
```

You can do it other ways, but if you want a collection of "server", then it must be in a grouping element like "servers".  You can't just have multiple "server" in a parent element that can also contain other types of children.  The tag within the group is almost always "add".

In any case "System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" definitely is not the correct type.

Comment: Interesting.  I never saw an example of the `add` element that used anything other than `name` and `value` attributes.  I'm trying this, but running into other problems.  Stay tuned....

Comment: Odd.  You've never seen a connection strings section?  Or pages/namespaces? Or httpHandlers?  Modules?  SqlDependencies? OutputCacheSettings?  Compilation/assemblies?

Comment: Although, system.webserver/runtime/assemblybinding does have multiple dependentAssembly children that don't use "add" as the tag but "dependentAssembly" as the tag with it's own children.  So you can do that too, it is just a lot less common.

Comment: The sarcasm isn't particularly appreciated (or necessary) but, yeah I'm a newbie at using System.Configuration and I'm not working with databases, or http, or ... so I haven't gone down those pathways in the massive but mostly unhelpful documentation in MSDN.  It's amazing how effectively they tell you everything except what you want to know. (I know, sarcasm on my part.)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be sarcastic, just not usual to run across someone who is trying to create custom configurations and hasn't worked with either the web or a database yet.